# Möbius transformation that maps an arc to the positive real axis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, transformation, polar-coordinates, mobius-transformation

[image: Figure]

The question asks to

1) Find a Möbius Transformation $T(z)$ such that the region bounded by the arcs $oac$ and $obc$ is transformed to a sector (of form {z : $\theta_1$< arg(z) < $\theta_2$ }). With origin being mapped to the origin, the arc $oac$ being mapped to the positive $\Bbb R$ axis.

2) Describe the image of region $G$ under $T(z)$ found in question 1.

Feel free to use the fact that $b$ = $\omega$ = $e^{i\pi/3}$

Comment: I tried to map $T(0)=0$ $T(1)=1$ and $T(\frac 32 + \frac{\sqrt(3)}{2}i)=\infty$ where the last point is what I found $c$ to be.
This gave me some transformation but I am not sure how to show that it maps the region in question 1 to a sector.

Comment: So far, I got a $T(z)=\frac {z(-\frac 12 - \frac {i\sqrt(3)}{2})} {z-\frac 32-\frac {i\sqrt(3)}{2}}$ and this does what the first questions specifies. I am just not sure how to map $G$ in the second questions

Comment: I think I got a solution. Will try post it later Today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1)*** So, I have found a transformation 
$T(z)=\frac {z(-\frac 12 - \frac {i\sqrt3}{2})} {z-\frac 32-\frac {i\sqrt3}{2}}$
by sending ($a$ to 1) ($0$ to 0) and ($c$ to $\infty$).

Using this, the region is Q1 is mapped to the sector

$[w:0<arg(w)<\frac{2\pi}{3}]$

***2)*** The region enclosed by disc $C_1$ is $T(C_1)$ which I found by replacing the $z$ with what $z$ is in terms of $w$

If $z=\frac {z(-\frac 12 - \frac {i\sqrt3}{2})} {z-\frac 32-\frac {i\sqrt3}{2}}$ then $w=\frac {w(\frac 32 + \frac {i\sqrt3}{2})} {w+\frac 12+\frac {i\sqrt3}{2}}$

So, $T(C_1)$ becomes the upper half plane after some algebra. If $w=u+iv$ then $T(C_1)=[w: Im(w)\ge 0]$

Region enclose by $C_3$ becomes $T(C_3)$ which is a disc with center $(\frac 14,\frac{\sqrt3}{4})$ and radius $\frac {\sqrt3}{2}$

$C_2$ gets mapped to an inequality but we dont need to find all of it because all we already have the intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$ which is the region $Oacb$ and we know that that becomes the sector mentioned in Q1

All we need to do now to find $T(G)$ is to subtract the region that the sector in Q1 gets mapped to and the sector $Obd$ from $T(C_1)$

We get $[w:Im(w)\ge 0] \setminus [[w:0<arg(w)<\frac{2\pi}{3}]\cup[w=u+iv: |w-\frac 14-\frac{\sqrt3}{4}|\le\frac34, s.t Re(w)=-\frac12]] $

Which looks like the sector in the image that I've attached[image]

The shaded region is $T(G)$